# OData get individual property: ~/entityset/key/navigation/property

Tags: rest, routes, odata

I need to get an entity's individual property from OData(V4) endpoint.

It is a simple project. Models, controllers and configurations files are [here](https://gist.github.com/Jamaxack/d468c2c37ce21a8f65e2ae56cc3edfe8)

The $select is working, but it is a little different than we want. We need to get just one property(not an entity with one property) to show in a report on somewhere.

Now I'm able to get individual navigation and normal properties:
http://localhost:64659/People(Guid)/Address,
http://localhost:64659/People(Guid)/Name,
http://localhost:64659/Address(Guid)/Name

But, the following URL is not working, because we trying to get navigation property's property:
http://localhost:64659/People(Guid)/Address/Name
And the error is:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:64659/People(c6ef0e71-2107-4d58-bf0d-12d38f25045a)/Address/Name'.",
    "innererror": {
        "message": "No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/navigation/property'.",
        "type": "",
        "stacktrace": ""
    }
}
```

}

I couldn't find anything to get this to work, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same issue and used $select

http://localhost:64659/Address(Guid)?$select=Name